# Changing background color dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

Right now there is a part of my page that has a list of objects. When you hover over them, the background turns a light yellow color and return to white when you mouseout. I want one of the objects to turn to a green background when a condition is met, and then go back to normal if it isn't met.

I have this happening with one issue: if the condition is met, it changes colors, and if it isn't I have it setting back to white. But now the light yellow mouseover won't work. The rest turns yellow but that one part stays white. I don't know how to "undo" my green color change in order to keep the mouseover/mouseout working correctly. Any help? Here is my code.

```
if($myID.text() === schedule.content().myId){                                                                           
    $myID.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");
    $stn.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");
    $miles.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");
    $worktag.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");                                      
}else{
    $myID.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    $stn.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    $miles.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    $worktag.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
}


$('#chevron').on('click', function() {

    if($myID.text() === schedule.content().myId){

        $myID.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");
        $stn.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");
        $miles.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");
        $worktag.css("background-color", "#AEAF93");                            
    }else{
        $myID.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        $stn.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        $miles.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        $worktag.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

    }
});

$sideBar.find('.myList').bind("mouseover", function(){
    var color  = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this).css("background", "#fffccc");
    $(this).bind("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#fff");
    });
});
```

Comment: apart from not understanding either why you're not using css for this, could you please post more code to show the entire relevant markup? maybe you're using css elsewhere which causes conflicting styles

Comment: I'm not working with a CSS class because it is a 200,000+ line application with a million things happening dynamically. putting it in CSS would never get it in the correct timing for everything. I do have a CSS file, but cannot encompass all things in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer to this.

CSS

```
.highlightedClass{
    background-color: #AEAF93;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
                //if condition      
                        if($td_ID.text() === schedule.content().idInFirstColumn){
                                $2nd_tr.addClass("highlightedClass");                       
                        }else{
                            if($2nd_tr.hasClass("highlightedClass")){
                                $2nd_tr.removeClass("highlightedClass");
                            }
                        }

                        $('#viewResultsButton').on('click', function(){
                            if($td_ID.text() === schedule.content().idInFirstColumn){
                                $2nd_tr.addClass("highlightedClass");   
                            }else{
                                if($2nd_tr.hasClass("highlightedClass")){
                                    $2nd_tr.removeClass("highlightedClass");
                                }
                            }
                        });


                //else condition
                        if($td_ID.text() === schedule.content().idInFirstColumn){
                                $tr.addClass("highlightedClass");                       
                        }else{

                            if($tr.hasClass("highlightedClass")){
                                $tr.removeClass("highlightedClass");
                            }
                        }




    //outside of huge if/else/for loop mess.

    $('#viewResultsButton').on('click', function(){
        var flag= false;
        $('#alteratePlan > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
            $td_ID = $(this).find('.td_id');
            if($td_ID.text() === ''){
                if(flag === true){
                    $(this).addClass("highlightedClass");
                    flag= true;
                }
            }else{
                if($td_ID.text() === schedule.content().idInFirstColumn){
                    if($(this).hasClass("highlightedClass")){
                        flag= true;
                    }else{
                        $(this).addClass("highlightedClass");
                        flag= true;
                    }
                }else{
                    flag= false;
                    if($(this).hasClass("highlightedClass")){
                        $(this).removeClass("highlightedClass");

                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var bg = "#FFFFFF";
if($myID.text() === schedule.content().myId) {
  bg = "#AEAF93";
}
$myID.css("background-color", bg);
$stn.css("background-color", bg);
$miles.css("background-color", bg);
$worktag.css("background-color", bg);
/*
the above can be done in one line :
$("#element1,#element2,#element3,#element4").css("background-color", bg);
*/
$('#chevron').on('click', function() {
  $myID.css("background-color", bg);
  $stn.css("background-color", bg);
  $miles.css("background-color", bg);
  $worktag.css("background-color", bg);
/*
the above can be done in one line :
$("#element1,#element2,#element3,#element4").css("background-color", bg);
*/
});
$sideBar.find('.myList').bind("mouseover", function(){
  $(this).css("background", "#fffccc");
}).bind("mouseout", function(){
  $(this).css("background", bg);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the shortcut way of doing this, but I'm afraid it does exactly the same thing, just in a different format. Any other ideas?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the problem here seems to be you have a mouseover and a click which conflict with each other because obviously mouseover will fire first and then onclick will fire so unless you go out and come back in it won't trigger the mouseover again.

Try this maybe

```
$("div input").hover(function() {
//Do you
});
```

Comment: thank you for explaining the order of the mouseover/click. I was unaware of priority there. I tried your code, but unfortunately it didn't do anything differently. Any other advice?